# Type mismatch resolving the error type when forwarding messages from a futures channel to a WebSocket Sink

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I'm trying to wrap my head around futures in Rust but I am confused by this code which is supposed to send messages arriving at `rx` to `sink`:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate websocket;

use websocket::message::OwnedMessage;
use websocket::server::InvalidConnection;
use websocket::async::Server;

use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use futures::{Future, Sink, Stream};
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use std::{thread, time};
use futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(5);
    thread::spawn(|| worker(rx));
    let mut i = 0;
    loop {
        let res = tx.clone().send(OwnedMessage::Text(format!("Test {}", i)));
        core.run(res);
        i += 1;
        let period = time::Duration::from_millis(200);
        thread::sleep(period);
    }
}

fn worker(rx: Receiver<OwnedMessage>) {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    // bind to the server
    let server = Server::bind("127.0.0.1:9000", &handle).unwrap();
    let f = server.incoming()
            // we don't wanna save the stream if it drops
            .map_err(|InvalidConnection { error, .. }| error)
            .for_each(|(upgrade, addr)| {
                // accept the request to be a ws connection if it does
                let f = upgrade
                    .use_protocol("rust-websocket")
                    .accept()
                    .and_then(|(s, _)| {
                        let (sink, stream) = s.split();
                        rx // using stream (echoing back) works
                            .forward(sink)
                            .map_err(|error| {
                                error
                            })
                            .and_then(|(a, sink)| {
                                sink.send(OwnedMessage::Close(None))
                            })
                    });

                handle.spawn(f.map_err(move |e| println!("Err"))
                    .map(move |_| println!("Done")));
                Ok(())
            });
    core.run(f).expect("somerror");
}
```

As noted in the comment, using `stream` as input works fine. When using `rx`, the compiler complains about a type mismatch regarding the error types (I believe):

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::stream::SplitSink<websocket::client::async::Framed<tokio_core::net::TcpStream, websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>> as futures::Sink>::SinkError == ()`
  --> src/main.rs:47:26
   |
47 |                         .forward(sink)
   |                          ^^^^^^^ expected enum `websocket::WebSocketError`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `websocket::WebSocketError`
              found type `()`

error[E0599]: no method named `map_err` found for type `futures::stream::Forward<futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<websocket::OwnedMessage>, futures::stream::SplitSink<websocket::client::async::Framed<tokio_core::net::TcpStream, websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:48:26
   |
48 |                         .map_err(|error| {
   |                          ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `map_err` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `futures::stream::Forward<futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<websocket::OwnedMessage>, futures::stream::SplitSink<websocket::client::async::Framed<tokio_core::net::TcpStream, websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>>> : futures::Future`
```

These are my dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
websocket = "0.20.0"
futures = "0.1"
tokio-core = "0.1"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving
>   `<futures::stream::SplitSink<
>         websocket::client::async::Framed<
>             tokio_core::net::TcpStream,
>             websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>>
>    as futures::Sink>::SinkError == ()`
> ```

We have two types here: `<futures::stream::SplitSink<...> as futures::Sink>::SinkError` and `()`. Where do these two types come from? Also, the first one is an unresolved associated type; perhaps we could resolve it to get some more insight? Let's trace it step by step.

First, we need to figure out why the compiler is trying to match these two types in the first place. If we look at the signature for [`forward`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.forward), we'll see the constraint `Self::Error: From<S::SinkError>`. `Self` is the type of the stream we're calling `forward` on, while `S` is the type of the sink that's passed as an argument to `forward`.

We're calling `forward` on `rx`, whose type is `futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver`. On the [documentation page for `Receiver`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html), we can see the following:

> ```
> impl<T> Stream for Receiver<T>
>   type Item = T
>   type Error = ()
> ```

This shows us where the `()` came from. Let's look at the `sink` argument now.

The type of `sink` is `futures::stream::SplitSink<websocket::client::async::Framed<tokio_core::net::TcpStream, websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>>` (we know this from the error message; the [RLS](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls) also confirms this). On the [documentation page for `SplitSink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/struct.SplitSink.html), we have:

> ```
> impl<S: Sink> Sink for SplitSink<S>
>   type SinkItem = S::SinkItem
>   type SinkError = S::SinkError
> ```

So `SplitSink`'s `SinkError` is the same as its inner sink's `SinkError`. The inner sink's type is `websocket::client::async::Framed<tokio_core::net::TcpStream, websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>>`. What does the [documentation for `Framed`](https://docs.rs/websocket/0.20.2/websocket/client/async/struct.Framed.html) say?

> ```
> impl<T, U> Sink for Framed<T, U>
> where
>     T: AsyncWrite,
>     U: Encoder,
>     <U as Encoder>::Error: From<Error>,
>   type SinkItem = <U as Encoder>::Item
>   type SinkError = <U as Encoder>::Error
> ```

`Framed` has two type parameters, but we only need to look at the second one, which is `websocket::async::MessageCodec<websocket::OwnedMessage>` here, to determine the `SinkError` type. Let's take a look at [`MessageCodec`](https://docs.rs/websocket/0.20.2/websocket/codec/ws/struct.MessageCodec.html) now. (*Note: `websocket::codec::ws::MessageCodec` is [reexported](https://docs.rs/websocket/0.20.2/websocket/async/index.html#reexports) as `websocket::async::MessageCodec`.*)

> ```
> impl<M> Decoder for MessageCodec<M>
> where
>     M: MessageTrait,
>   type Item = OwnedMessage
>   type Error = WebSocketError
> ```

Ah ha! The sink produces errors of type [`WebSocketError`](https://docs.rs/websocket/0.20.2/websocket/result/enum.WebSocketError.html).

---

Now that we've figured out the types, let's go back to why we cared about the types in the first place. We were trying to understand why the constraint `Self::Error: From<S::SinkError>` wasn't met on the call to `forward`. We now know that the compiler is trying to resolve `(): From<WebSocketError>`. It looks like there's no `impl From<WebSocketError> for ()`. Let's verify this:

```
extern crate websocket;

fn main() {
    let a = websocket::result::WebSocketError::NoDataAvailable;
    let () = From::from(a);
}
```

Indeed, this fails to compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::convert::From<websocket::WebSocketError>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:14
  |
5 |     let () = From::from(a);
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<websocket::WebSocketError>` is not implemented for `()`
  |
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

---

We can work around the missing implementation by using [`sink_map_err`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html#method.sink_map_err) to change `sink`'s error type.

```
let (sink, stream) = s.split();
let sink = sink.sink_map_err(|_| ()); // <<<<<
rx
    .forward(sink)
    .and_then(|(a, sink)| {
        sink.send(OwnedMessage::Close(None))
    })
```

This solves the call to `forward`, but now the result of this closure doesn't compose with `upgrade.use_protocol("rust-websocket").accept()`, which still has `WebSocketError` as its error type. It makes more sense to change `rx`'s error type instead. But how do we construct a `WebSocketError` from a `()`, which carries no information?

You might be wondering, why does `Receiver` use `()` for its error type? If we look at the [source code](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/src/futures/sync/mpsc/mod.rs.html#903-943), we can see that in fact, `poll` *never* returns an error. I think it would be more appropriate if the error type was `!` (the never type) or some other void type, to clearly indicate that errors are impossible; there's an [issue open on futures](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/476) requesting this change for futures 0.2.

Since errors are impossible, we don't need to construct a `WebSocketError`; we can just diverge instead, for example by panicking.

```
fn worker(rx: Receiver<OwnedMessage>) {
    let rx = rx.map_err(|()| panic!("Receiver should never fail!"));
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    // bind to the server
    let server = Server::bind("127.0.0.1:9000", &handle).unwrap();
    let f = server.incoming()
            // we don't wanna save the stream if it drops
            .map_err(|InvalidConnection { error, .. }| error)
            .for_each(|(upgrade, addr)| {
                // accept the request to be a ws connection if it does
                let f = upgrade
                    .use_protocol("rust-websocket")
                    .accept()
                    .and_then(|(s, _)| {
                        let (sink, stream) = s.split();
                        rx
                            .forward(sink)
                            .and_then(|(a, sink)| {
                                sink.send(OwnedMessage::Close(None))
                            })
                    });

                handle.spawn(f.map_err(move |e| println!("Err"))
                    .map(move |_| println!("Done")));
                Ok(())
            });
    core.run(f).expect("somerror");
}
```

Now, there's still an error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:43:31
   |
30 |     let rx = rx.map_err(|()| panic!("Receiver should never fail!"));
   |         -- captured outer variable
...
43 |                     .and_then(|(s, _)| {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Why is the closure trying to move `rx`? Because `forward` takes `self` by value. Why is the closure an `FnMut`? Watch out, [`Future::and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then) requires an `FnOnce` (it's valid to move a value from a captured variable into an `FnOnce` closure), but [`Stream::for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each) requires an `FnMut`. This makes sense: `for_each` will invoke the closure once for each incoming connection!

The channels you're using are [multi-producer, *single-consumer*](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sync/mpsc/index.html) (hence the name *mpsc*), but you're trying to have multiple consumers here (each connection is trying to read from the receiver). I'll leave it to you to fix this design issue in your program. Remember that there can be multiple concurrent client connections!

Comment: Thank you for the great, in-depth answer. This was indeed an design flaw, thank you for pointing this out. I solved it by creating a channel per connection and storing the senders in a map, so that the main thread can send to every connection.